# Record Editing in modal LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning

Hello I have LWC app which shows contact records and on clicking the edit button modal opens which shows editable fields of row. problem is that I'm stuck at one point where it gives error as - promise rejection [Object object] error
I need your help, please guide me how to fix this and please pardon if my question is silly post your answer, I'm new in this environment and not able to complete this from last 10 days. Kindly help.

//html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Contact Records">
    
        <lightning-datatable data={wireContact.data} columns={columns} key-field="id" hide-checkbox-column="true"  onrowaction={handleRowAction}></lightning-datatable>
        
        <template if:true={modalContainer}>
            <section  class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={closeModalAction}>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" alternative-text="close" variant="inverse" size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                        </button>
                        
                        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Contact Record Detail</h2>
                    </header>

                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
                        <thead>    
                            <tr>  
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                 <th>Email Name</th>
                                  <th>Phone Name</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>

                        <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                <td> <lightning-input type="text" label="First name" value={contactRow.FirstName} onchange={handleSave}> </lightning-input> </td>

                                <td>  <lightning-input type="text" label="Last name" value={contactRow.LastName} onchange={handleSave}> </lightning-input>   </td>

                                <td>  <lightning-input type="Email" label="Email" value={contactRow.Email}  onchange={handleSave}> </lightning-input> </td>

                                <td>  <lightning-input  type="tel" label="Phone"  value={contactRow.Phone} onchange={handleSave}> </lightning-input> </td>
                            </tr>
                         </tbody>   
                        </table>

                    </div>
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    
                        <lightning-button class="slds-p-horizontal_medium" variant="brand" label="Close" title="Close"  onclick={closeModalAction}></lightning-button>
                        <lightning-button class="slds-p-horizontal_medium" variant="brand" label="Save" title="Save" type="submit" onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button>
                    
                </footer> 
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

---

// JS

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/LWCExampleController.getContacts';
import saveRecord from '@salesforce/apex/LWCExampleController.saveRecord';

const columns=[
    {label: 'View',type: 'button-icon', initialWidth: 75, typeAttributes: { iconName: 'action:preview', title: 'Preview',
     variant: 'border-filled', alternativeText: 'View'}
      },
    { label: 'First Name',fieldName: 'FirstName', },
    { label: 'Last Name',   fieldName: 'LastName', },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email'},
    { label: 'Phone',   fieldName: 'Phone'}
];

export default class LwcDataTableRowAction extends LightningElement {
  @track columns = columns;
  @track contactRow={};
  @track rowOffset = 0;  
  @track modalContainer = false;
  @track saveDraftValues = [];
  @track contacts;

   @wire(getContacts) wireContact;
 
   handleRowAction(event){
      const dataRow = event.detail.row;
      window.console.log('dataRow@@ ' + dataRow);
      this.contactRow=dataRow;
      window.console.log('contactRow## ' + dataRow);
      this.modalContainer=true;
   }

  
   // handleChange(event){
//    if(event.target.label=='First name'){                 
   //        this.contactRow.FirstName = event.target.value;
   //    }

   async handleSave(){
      try{
         await saveRecord({
            try(){
            let contactList = [this.contactRow.FirstName];
            
       })
   }
   catch(error){
        console.log(error); 
   }
   }
   closeModalAction(){
    this.modalContainer=false;
   }
}
```

---

// apex class

```
public inherited sharing class LWCExampleController {

    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true)
    public static List<Contact> getContacts() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email 
                FROM Contact 
                WHERE Email != null 
                AND Phone != null 
                ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC NULLS LAST limit 10];
    } 

    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true)
   public static void saveRecord(Contact contactToUpdate){
    
    update contactToUpdate; 
   }
}
```

---

// meta file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
      </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Method marked as `@AuraEnabled(Cacheable = true)` cannot have DML (insert, update, upsert, delete). What does mean?

Your apex method should look like that:

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static void saveRecord(Contact contactToUpdate) {
   update contactToUpdate; 
}
```

- You should not perform DML (update) `onchange`. It's better to gather data `onchange` and add some button called "Update"

```html
<tr>
    <td> <lightning-input type="text" label="First name" data-field="FirstName" value={contactRow.FirstName} onchange={handleContactChange}> </lightning-input> </td>
    <td>  <lightning-input type="text" label="Last name" data-field="LastName" value={contactRow.LastName} onchange={handleContactChange}> </lightning-input>   </td>
    <td>  <lightning-input type="Email" label="Email" data-field="Email" value={contactRow.Email}  onchange={handleContactChange}> </lightning-input> </td>
    <td>  <lightning-input  type="tel" label="Phone"  data-field="Phone" value={contactRow.Phone} onchange={handleContactChange}> </lightning-input> </td>
</tr>

//html
<lightning-button variant="base" label="Base" title="Update" onclick={handleUpdate} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
```

```js
handleContactChange(event) {
    const value = event.detail.value;
    const field = event.target.dataset.field;
    
    this.contactRow = {
        ...this.contactRow, 
        [field]: value
    };
}

handleRowAction(event){
   this.contactRow = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail.row));

   this.modalContainer = true;
}

handleUpdate() {
    saveRecord({ contactToUpdate: this.contactRow })
    .then(result => {
      //saveRecord it's void so. 
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.error(error);
    })
}
```

---

Code can be done better, but more or less this is a solution.

Comment: Thank you Piotr, I replaced my code with this, while running it's giving t is undefined error. actually I removed my commented handleChange and async handleSave method and pasted this JS code. am i missing something Piotr ? please help

Comment: When exactly are you getting error? When updating fields or during the save?

Comment: Yes Piotr, as soon as I start typing to edit, it gives error popup as - TypeError: t is undefined
throws at https://abhi01-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/QPQi8lbYE8YujG6og6Dqgw/aura_prod.js:65:72033

Comment: Try `const field = event.currentTarget.dataset.field;`

Comment: Do you know how to debug with Chrome Console?

Comment: I checked with this Piotr, still it throws same error

Comment: actually i'm doing on firefox

Comment: okay I will check with chrome also

Comment: here in chrome it says - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138950/discussion-between-abhishek-sharma-and-piotr-gajek).

Comment: forum didn't allow me to upvote due to less than 15 reputation but I want to let forum moderators and other readers know, Piotr spent more than hour and fix many errors code had. this comment is to mark upvote to Piotr.